# Download prerequisites from the same location as my application - Where do I put the files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, prerequisites

I have some prerequisite files that need to go into a setup project in Visual Studio 2010, but, I can't figure out WHERE to put the files.  See error message below (when building the setup project).  The file CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_1.msi , I downloaded it, but not matter where I put it in the setup project, I still get the same error.  Where is VS2010 looking for these files?

```
To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_1.msi' for item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.
```

Answer (score 0):

For VS2010, copy CRRuntime_xxx.msi file to

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
```

For VS2015, copy CRRuntime_xxx.msi file to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0
```